# SQL get only unique combination of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

I have table with:

```
A     B
1     2
2     1
```

and i trying using sql command to get **only one combination**

```
A     B
1     2
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A canonical way in standard SQL is:

```
select a, b
from t
where a < b
union all
select a, b
from t
where a > b and not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a);
```

Note that this assumes no duplicates or equal values.  You can easily handle these using `select distinct` and `<=` comparisons.  In my experience, this problem often arises when there are at most two rows per pair.

This preserves the original values.  So, if you start with:

```
1    2
5    4
```

You will get that in the result set.

If you don't care about ordering, then many databases support `least()`/`greatest()`:

```
select least(a, b) as a, greatest(a, b) as b
from t
group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b);
```

You can do the same thing with `case` expressions.  Or, more simply as:

```
select distinct least(a, b) as a, greatest(a, b) as b
from t;
```

Comment: ...for the second statement, would a `DISTINCT` be more idiomatic?

Comment: Neat.  For first one maybe s/where a < b/where a <= b/ ?

Comment: @jgreve . . . It depends.  But I did elaborate in the answer about the assumptions in the current version and how to extend it.